# How to keep text visible inside container if too long without wrapping

Tags: html, css

I have a structure like this:

```css
td {
  height: 50px;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  height: 30px;
}

.line {
  background-color: green;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div style="padding: 20px;">
  <div class="box">
  <table style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
    <tbody>
      <tr style="background-color: yellow;">
        <td>
          <div class="content" style="left: 20%">
            <div class="line" style="width: 30%"></div>
            <div>
              <span>Some text</span>
            </div>
          </div>      
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="background-color: blue;">
        <td>
          <div class="content" style="left: 60%">
            <div class="line" style="width: 30%"></div>
            <div>
              <span>Some more text</span>
            </div>
          </div>      
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="background-color: orange;">
        <td>
          <div class="content" style="left: 80%">
            <div class="line" style="width: 30%"></div>
            <div>
            <span>Some long text that should be bumped to the left to remain visible</span>
            </div>
          </div>      
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/je78nz93/

The green lines needs to be positioned relative to the `td` it is contained within. 
The black box should be left aligned with the green line above, with the text following the black box. 
If the text is too long, it and the black box needs to be moved to the left to remain visible.

Please help me find an elegant solution to this.

Comment: It would be helpful if you made a diagram of the your object.

Comment: Table has overflow hidden. When you apply overflow hidden, you not able to see the text

Comment: @hungerstar what kind of diagram do you want? It's all there in the fiddle.

Comment: @Nisar I don't want the text to go outside the box, I want to keep it within.

Comment: you force it to left:80%, and you don't want overflow and no wrap, the content take like 50% of the width, really? you need a better design, to be honest.

Comment: try something like this? @henningc https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/je78nz93/1/

Comment: @DanielH Yes, that's why I'm asking. This is an example to highlight my problem. I just want to align the text with the green line if there is room, if not, display the whole thing.

Comment: @henningc it can't all be there in the fiddle otherwise the fiddle would be the solution. Provide a diagram of the intended layout.

Comment: @DanielH your solution also moves the green bar. I need to move just the text.

Comment: @hungerstar this is what it should look like: https://jsfiddle.net/ayfer3s3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use `margin` instead `position`

- **`edit`**

  - **deleted** :*`float` the span where stands the long text.*
  - **inserted** :or use `inline-block` and `direction`. Might be some sides effect on punctution.
  - **`end edit`**
- use `vw` unit to set `.line`'s `width`

still, i do not get the purpose of this layout :(

```css
td {
  height: 50px;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  height: 30px;
}

.line {
  background-color: green;
  height: 10px;
  width:30vw;
}

tr  span {
  display:inline-block;
  max-width:100%;
  white-space:nowrap;
  direction:rtl;
}
```

```html
<div style="padding: 20px;">
  <div class="box">
  <table style="width: 100%;overflow:hidden; ">
    <tbody>
      <tr style="background-color: yellow;">
        <td>
          <div class="content" style="margin-left: 20%">
            <div class="line"></div>
            <div>
              <span>Some text</span>
            </div>
          </div>      
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="background-color: blue;">
        <td>
          <div class="content" style="margin-left: 60%">
            <div class="line"></div>
            <div>
              <span>Some more text</span>
            </div>
          </div>      
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="background-color: orange;">
        <td>
          <div class="content" style="margin-left: 80%">
            <div class="line"></div>
            <div>
            <span>Some long text that should be bumped to the left to remain visible</span>
            </div>
          </div>      
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/je78nz93/2/

Comment: That looks like it might be a solution :) I'll have to test it when I get to work tomorrow, and give you credit for the answer if it works. Thank you

Comment: Hm, no, I didn't notice the special rules you had for the last span, that won't work. The order of the rows doesn't mean anything, and the positions can vary within each row. I need a generic solution that lets the text respect the boundaries of the outer container.

Comment: @henningc an hint would be direction to reverse text overflow : https://jsfiddle.net/je78nz93/3/  see side effect with punctuation https://jsfiddle.net/je78nz93/4/ and text overflowing on left https://jsfiddle.net/je78nz93/5/ if table-layout is set to fixed and text wider than the table

Comment: This looks good. I had actually tested rtl before, but got into trouble with the black square. I tried to put it inside the span now after the text, and it looks like it works. I'll test some more at work tomorrow. Thanks :)

Comment: this got me nudged in the right direction (:D), thanks! I'll mark it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the code. But, it is not responsive.

```css
td {
  height: 50px;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0%;
  background-color: red;
  height: 30px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.line {
  background-color: green;
  height: 10px;
}

.tdContainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div style="padding: 20px;">
  <div class="box">
    <table style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
      <tbody>
        <tr style="background-color: yellow;">
          <td>
            <div class="tdContainer">
              <div class="content" style="width: 80%">
                <div class="line" style="width: 30%"></div>
                <div>
                  <span>Some text</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="background-color: blue;">
          <td>
            <div class="tdContainer">
              <div class="content" style="width: 60%">
                <div class="line" style="width: 30%"></div>
                <div>
                  <span>Some more text</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="background-color: orange;">
          <td>
            <div class="tdContainer">
              <div class="content" style="width: 40%">
                <div class="line" style="width: 30%"></div>
                <div>
                  <span>Some long text that should be bumped to the left to remain visible</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
</div>
```